# Unable to change background colour for new button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I am using XAML and MVVM pattern for an application.

In part of my application I have a window split into 2 parts, a left column and right hand column/area

In the left column are a row of buttons ( generated on loading the window )

The right column/area will display a group of buttons depending on which button the user clicks in the left column, so for example say I have 4 department buttons in the left column, each department button will have a different number of stock items.

If I click button 1 in the left column, I do some code in the viewmodel to fetch the names of items in that department. And then I build a new observableCollection to display in the right column/area.

So this isnt a problem, the right amount of buttons get generated each time ok.
However when I try to change the background colour dynamically in the ViewModel, the colour is NOT upodated in the view.

The strange thing is, I can change the content, forecolour and other properties but just not the background colour. It appears the background will only generate correctly if loaded and run time. I cant change it otherwise while using the window.

I have tried Brushes, creating and assigning new style and even clearing the dependancy property of the button ( .ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty) )

Would any one know how i can get the background to change colour while the window is open and when i want to generate a set of buttons dynamically in my viewmodel?

Many thanks all... I have attached my XAML and C# snippet, the

XAML :

```
<dxd:DockLayoutManager Name="dlSalesScreen">
    <dxd:DockLayoutManager.LayoutRoot>
        <dxd:LayoutGroup Name="Root" Orientation="Horizontal" AllowSplitters="False">

            <dxd:LayoutPanel AllowClose="False" AllowRename="False" 
                             Caption="Departments" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                             CaptionAlignMode="AutoSize"
                             CaptionImageLocation="BeforeText" ShowPinButton="False" >

                <!-- Scrollviewer for department buttons-->
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="deptScrollviewer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="185" Height="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Orientation="Vertical" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </dxd:LayoutPanel>

            <dxd:LayoutPanel AllowClose="False" AllowRename="False" 
                             Caption="Available stock in department" Width="Auto" 
                             CaptionAlignMode="AutoSize"
                             CaptionImageLocation="BeforeText"  ShowPinButton="False">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Scrollviewer for stock buttons-->
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="stockScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="VerticalOnly">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StockItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="400" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Fill="{StaticResource BottomRectangleGradient}" />
                    <Grid Name="gridButtonHolder" Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <GroupBox x:Name="grpStockItem" Grid.Column="0" Header="Selected Item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" >
                            <Label x:Name="lblStockName" Content="{Binding SelectedStockItemLabel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </GroupBox>
                        <Button Name="btnSave" Content="Apply" Command="{Binding ConfirmSelectionCommand}" dxc:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue" Grid.Column="1" Width="110" Height="42" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
                        <Button Name="btnClose" Content="Cancel" dxc:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Blue" Grid.Column="2" Width="110" Height="42" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </dxd:LayoutPanel>
        </dxd:LayoutGroup>
    </dxd:DockLayoutManager.LayoutRoot>
</dxd:DockLayoutManager>
```

C#

```
 void DeptClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDeptID = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());

        _stockButtons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

        if (StockItemCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < StockItemCount; i++)
            {
                //_stockButtons.Add(new Button());
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;

                btn.Height = 100;
                btn.Width = 100;
                btn.Content = i.ToString();

                _stockButtons.Add(btn);
            }
        }

        RaisePropertyChanged("StockItems");
    }

 public ObservableCollection<Button> Departments
    {
        get
        {
            if (_deptButtons == null)
            {
                _deptButtons = new ObservableCollection<Button>();

                for (int i = 0; i < DeptCount; i++)
                {
                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Content = DepartmentNames[i];
                    button.Tag = DepartmentIDs[i].ToString();
                    button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(DeptClicked);

                    button.Width = 128;
                    button.Height = 100;

                    _deptButtons.Add(button);
                }

            }
            return _deptButtons;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DevExpress controls but it looks like your new button has that same "Office2007Blue" theme that the Apply and Cancel buttons have. Perhaps the DevExpress theme manager taking over the Background of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
Button btn = new Button(); 
btn.Background = Brushes.Green;    
btn.Height = 100; btn.Width = 100;
btn.Content = i.ToString();

ThemeManager.SetThemeName(btn, "None");

_stockButtons.Add(btn);
```

Class ThemeMagager is in namespace DevExpress.Xpf.Core.

Comment: Hi Kmatyaszek... THANKKKK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU!!!!!!!! Your a genius!! Cant thank you enough... spent 2 days on this literally scratching my head! Thanks again :)